# RMarkdown cannot knit: html_dependency not found

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, rnotebook

I am trying to create an html file using `RMarkdown` (using the sample .Rmd in RStudio). When I click `Knit`, I am getting the following message:

> Error: path for html_dependency not found: Execution halted.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling both R and RStudio, as well as all of the packages required for markdown. I am running the most current version of RStudio (1.1.383), and R (3.4.2), and all of my packages are up to date.

This is not my first time using RStudio or markdown, but I have yet to get markdown work on this computer. I have not made any changes to the default markdown file.

```
traceback()
8: stop("path for html_dependency not found: ", file, call. = FALSE)
7: FUN(X[[i]], ...)
6: lapply(dependencies, validate_html_dependency)
5: dependency_resolver(all_dependencies)
4: html_extras_for_document(knit_meta, runtime, dependency_resolver, 
   format_deps)
3: base(...)
2: output_format$pre_processor(yaml_front_matter, utf8_input, runtime, 
   knit_meta, files_dir, output_dir)
1: rmarkdown::render("test.rmd", "html_document")
```

Comment: The most recent version of R isn't 1.1.383, it's 3.4.2.

Comment: Its the current preview version of RStudio. What OS? Do you have admin rights? Is it a computer at work or your personal one? Does your user have a virtual drive maybe?

Comment: Windows 10, yes, work, perhaps but how would I check that?